# ng command not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

Previously I created a project in a new folder that created successfully but I am trying to create a new project again then I am getting an error:

> You cannot use the new command inside an angular-cli project

So please tell me how to solve this error. I have read some answers that say to  remove a json file and node_module folder.

I deleted but now I am getting that error still. I even completely deleted the project but still getting that error.

So please solve in a proper solution

Comment: Are you trying to create a new `ng` project inside an existing `ng` project?

Comment: no i am writing this command - ng new ram_project

Comment: The error message is self explanatory... Don't run `ng new` from inside a folder that already contains a project created with angular cli

Comment: inside that folder i deleted the previous project

Comment: works but not that folder i dont know why didn't created that place even the folder was empty